# How to provide clients with an admin portal on a custom from-scratch site?

Tags: html, web, content-management-system

I am in the process of becoming a self-taught web developer and working to understand the various paradigms of creating and deploying websites. As I currently understand it, there are three (VASTLY OVERSIMPLIFIED) paradigms:

- Designed and managed through a CMS platform (simple/limited: Squarespace, Wix; complex/powerful: Wordpress, Joomla)
- Static site created from scratch (custom HTML/CSS/Javascript or purchased/modified template)
- Dynamic web application (including server-side logic, databases, likely front- and back-end frameworks, etc)

The way I see it, the first and last ones include easy ways to give some administrative powers to your clients, so they can add new content (as one example). CMS already includes a full admin portal, and web app frameworks like Django typically allow you to provide an administrative interface for loading new content.

How would you handle this with a custom static site? If you're typically just loading static HTML/CSS/JS files onto the client's web hosting, it seems like they would need to loop you or another developer in every time they wanted to make a change to the site. Is this true? Or is there a way of giving them some sort of interface to make changes?

Also if any of my assumptions above are wrong, I will gladly take correction!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, static sites are usually generated with a static site generator. You would give the clients access to this generator, so they can change the content, re-generate the desired site and push the changes live.

We always used a cronjob for pushing the changes to the live version.

Answer (score 0):

Static sites, as their name, are static, and you can not change them.

If you decide to change them, you should change the code.

In the real world, there is no static site, and most of sites are dynamic.

CMS is a kind of ready dynamic site.

Comment: Wouldn't a personal site, such as a resume page or an artist's portfolio, be best created as a static site? They wouldn't really need their site to interact with a database at all, unless they wanted a blog. In most of the entry-level articles and courses on web design/development, the model commonly taught is a series of separate but related HTML, CSS, and (sometimes) JS files that are uploaded to a server via FTP independently of any CMS. Is this model not actually used?

Comment: Actually, It could be, but It's not a good solution. for example, if you want to add any thing to your resume, you should change the code, and upload it again. but in dynamic websites, admin has a panel, and can change the content easily.
The best easiest way for a personal website is using The CMS

Answer (score 0):

Static sites are, as the name suggests, **static**.

They do not have a database, so there is no way to provide **[role-based access control (RBAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)**. You also don't have access to any server-side logic, so there's no way for users to upload any files. You might be able to `PUT` a file through **[`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)**, though most servers are not configured to handle this, for good reason; you wouldn't be able to add any real security validation to prevent users from uploading any malicious files.

If you want either of those things, go with options 1 or 3 (option 1 is essentially a prepackaged option 3 anyway).